# Setting variable through reflection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to set a variable value knowing it's name as a string, e.g.:

```
//JAVASCRIPT version
myObj["varName"] = someValue;
```

Reading few other answers on stackoverflow.com I found a following solution

```
// C# version
myObj.GetType ().GetProperty ("varName").SetValue (myObj, someValue, null);
```

Compiling this gives me a NullReference exception although I can clearly see that my class has a **public** variable with exactly the same name.

I'm new to C# and probably missing something, I would appreciate if somebody could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description `myVar` is a field.  Hence you need to be using `GetField` not `GetProperty`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick if the variable is a field:

```
myObj.GetType().GetField("varName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(myObj, someValue, null);
```

If it is a property:

```
myObj.GetType().GetProperty("varName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(myObj, someValue, null);
```